# Unhandled Exception: InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>

Tags: json, list, flutter, dart

I am trying to get the JSON response from the server and output it to the console.

```
Future<String> login() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("https://etrans.herokuapp.com/test/2"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    this.setState(() {
      data = json.decode(response.body);
    });


    print(data[0].name);
    return "Success!";
  }
```

> Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is
> not a subtype of type 'List

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Here are 2 common ways this could go wrong:

1. If your response is a json array like

   ```
   [
       {
         key1: value1,
         key2: value2,
         key3: value3,
       },
       {
         key1: value1,
         key2: value2,
         key3: value3,
       },

       .....
   ]
   ```

   Then, we use **`data[0]["name"]`**, not **`data[0].name`**
   Unless we cast to an object that has the name property, we cannot use **`data[0].name`**

   *We cast like this `data = json.decode(response.body).cast<ObjectName>();`*

   *`ObjectName` can be whatever object you want (Inbuilt or Custom). But make sure it has the name property*
2. If your response is a JSON object like

   ```
   {
       dataKey: [
         {
           key1: value1,
           key2: value2,
           key3: value3,
         } 
       ] 
   }
   ```

   Then `json.decode` will return a **Map**, not a **List**

   ```
   Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
   List<dynamic> data = map["dataKey"];
   print(data[0]["name"]);
   ```

Comment: and how we convert List<dynamic> to List<Map<String, dynamic>

Comment: @Diyen Momjang, my array is like datakey:[{key:value}, {key:value}, {key:value}] and I'm facing the same issue, can you help me out?

Comment: check api response formate.  e.x => var decode= json.decoder(response.body)

Comment: my json result is like this : {"key":"value","array:[{"key":"value"}]"}, then how i can get response in my list..can you please help me sir.....i am trying like this...List<UserPostModel> myList = [];var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());


    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      for (var i in data){
        myList.add(UserPostModel.fromJson(i));
      }
      print(myList);
      return myList;

Comment: how to add in a array? i am trying to add in array like this for (var i in data1){
        myList.add(UserPostModel.fromJson(i));
      } but, its give me error "String' is not a subtype of type 'bool?".  @Diyen Momjang

Answer (score 88):

You can use
`new Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value);`

Comment: use response.body instead of snapshot.value

Comment: he used snippet for firebasedatabase

Comment: give some more details

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I had a json response in this format

{
  "name":"Nelson K",
 "gender" : "Male"

}

Answer (score 19):

Easiest way (one dimensional):

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>.from(json.decode(response.body));

print(data['name']);
```

Answer (score 19):

You are trying to case an Instance of `InternalLinkedHashMap` which is not possible.

You should *Serialize* and *deserialize* it back to `Map<String, dynamic>`.

```
InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> invalidMap;

final validMap =
        json.decode(json.encode(invalidMap)) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

Comment: i got the same issue. do you mind to check it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67564553/unhandled-exception-type-internallinkedhashmapstring-dynamic-is-not-a-sub

Answer (score 7):

You have to convert the `runtimeType` of `data` from `_InternalLinkedHashMap` to an actual `List`.

One way is to use the `List.from`.

```dart
final _data = List<dynamic>.from(
  data.map<dynamic>(
    (dynamic item) => item,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need work with generic fields has a workaround:

```
class DicData
{
  int tot;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> fields;

  DicData({
    this.tot,
    this.fields
  });

 factory DicData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return DicData(
        tot: parsedJson['tot'],
        //The magic....
        fields : parsedJson["fields"] = (parsedJson['fields'] as List)
            ?.map((e) => e == null ? null : Map<String, dynamic>.from(e))
            ?.toList()
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get this error if you are using [retrofit.dart](https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart) and declare the wrong return type for your annotated methods:

```
@GET("/search")
Future<List<SearchResults>> getResults(); 
// wrong! search results contains a List but the actual type returned by that endpoint is SearchResults
```

vs

```
@GET("/search")
Future<SearchResults> getResults(); 
// correct for this endpoint - SearchResults is a composite with field for the list of the actual results
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Create a List Data
2. Use Map to decode the JSON file
3. Use the List object Data to fetch the name of the JSON files
4. With the help of index and the list object I have printed the items dynamically from the JSON file

```
setState(){

    Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
    Data  = map["name"];
}

// for printing
Data[index]['name1'].toString(),
```

Comment: This worked for me..1) Create a List Data ,2) Use Map to decode the json file ,3) Use the List object Data to fetch the name of the json files.4) With the help of index and the list object i have printed the items dynamically from the json file.

Answer (score 1):

If your working with Firebase Cloud,make sure that you're not trying to add multiple data with same DocumentID;

```
firestore.collection('user').document(UNIQUEID).setData(educandos[0].toJson()).
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this error could pop up depending on various developer faults.
In my case, I was using an `EasyLocalization` key but without defining it under `asset/lang/en_US.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

To convert from _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> to Map<String, double> I used

```
Map<String,double>.from(json['rates'])
```

Answer (score 0):

this.categories = data.map((category) => Category.fromJson(category)).toList();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

I had the same error using `json_annotation`, `json_serializable`, `build_runner`. It occurs when calling the `ClassName.fromJson()` method for a class that had a class property (example: class User has a property class Address).

As a solution, I modified the generated `*.g.dart` files of each class, by changing `Map<String, dynamic>)` to `Map<dynamic, dynamic>)` in everywhere there is a deep conversion inside the method `_$*FromJson`

The only problem is that you have to change it again every time you regenerate your files.