# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

im beginner in flutter. i have an error to get JSON response like this.

```
{
    dataKey: [
      {
        key1: value1,
        key2: value2,
        key3: value3,
      } 
    ] 
}
```

I've been looking for this problem in the forum and I found like this.

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
List<dynamic> data = map["dataKey"];
print(data[0]["name"]);
```

but I don't understand how to write the function. this is my code.

```
Future<Map> getData() async {
var response = await http.get(
    'https://api.batulimee.com/v1_ship/port_detail?port_id=${widget.list[widget.index] 
['port_id'].toString()}');
return json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
}

FutureBuilder<Map>(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? new Ports(
                    list: snapshot.data['data'],
                  )
                : new Container();
          },
        ),

class Ports extends StatelessWidget {
final List list;
Ports({this.list});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: list.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    return Card(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Text(
          list[i]['port_website'].toString(),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
}
}
```

and the error like this.

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
```

im sorry for asking the same question because i dont understand about it :(. thank you for helping

Comment: what you get for `response` ? Can you print out it ?

Comment: seems like the JSON response above

Comment: `Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
List<dynamic> data = map["dataKey"];
print(data[0]["key1"]);` Did it print out value1?

Comment: i got that function code from forum, but i dont know how to write it into my code. :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430061/unhandled-exception-internallinkedhashmapstring-dynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of  i got the problem solve from this. but idk how to implement it

Comment: put the code before `return json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>; ` and check. If it printing value1, then we can proceed on next step.

Comment: Define final Map list;

Comment: how about map["datakey"];? just leave it like that?

Comment: cannot work :\ i dont know how to implement it Future<Map> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        'https://api.batulima.com/v1_ships/port_detail?port_id=${widget.list[widget.index]['port_id'].toString()}');
    Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
    List<dynamic> data = map["data"];
    print(data[0]["name"]);
    return json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
  //define your model in defineModel
  Map<int, defineModel> yourMap = {};
```

and get method:

```
      Future<void> getFavoriteList() async {
        try {
          final response = await http.get('url');
          final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
          if (extractedData == null) {
            return;
          }
          final Map<int, defineModel> loadedProducts = {};
        
          final lastExtract = extractedData['dataKey'];
            
          lastExtract.forEach((prodData) {
            loadedProducts.putIfAbsent(
            //you Must Define A UniqueKey in here
              key,
              () => defineModel(
                key1: prodData['key1'],
                key2: prodData['key2'],
                key3: prodData['key3'],
              ),
            );
          });        
          yourMap = loadedProducts;
        } catch (error) {
          throw (error);
        }
      }
```

Comment: im sorry,but i dont get it :\. thank you for answering btw