# error type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: json, api, flutter, asynchronous, dart

I have an error when trying to parse my JSON and display it in the text, not as a `listview`.

Below is my JSON structure.

```
{
"status": "success",
    "data": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": afri,
            "class": 3c'
            },
    "message": "Success"
}
```

and this is my Future API async.

```
Future<Map> getData() async {
var response = await http.get(
    'url');
return json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
}
```

and this is my code to display the JSON.

```
Container(
          child: FutureBuilder<Map>(
            future: getData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(snapshot.data["data"]);
              return Card(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text(
                    data['port_website'],
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

and when I'm trying to get the data, I got an error like this.

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

which code should I fix?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430061/unhandled-exception-internallinkedhashmapstring-dynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of

Comment: i've read that questio before. but still, i dont get it. im sorry, its hard for me because im beginner. :(

Comment: I think you need to change this `Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(snapshot.data["data"]);` with this `List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode(snapshot.data["data"]);`

Comment: and i got error like this

Comment: ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("data")
The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>
lib\…\Destination\destinationDetail.dart:304
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to convert the runtime of data from `_InternalLinkedHashMap` to an exact list.

You can use `List.form` to achieve it.

```
final _data = List<dynamic>.from(
  data.map<dynamic>(
    (dynamic item) => item,
  ),
);
```

**Edit 1**

Worked for me. Try this

`new Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value);`

Comment: Can upvote the answer if it's solved your issue. So it'll be helpful for others as well. Thanks