# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>'

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to get json data from the server

#### here is the code:

```
 void main() async{
      List data = await getData();
      print(data);
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    Future<List> getData() async {
      String myUrl = "https://dashboard.ssitanas.com/public/api/categories";
      http.Response response = await http.get(myUrl, headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      });
      return json.decode(response.body);
    
    }
```

## what is the problem ?

Comment: add your JSON response.

Comment: {
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "Category_name": "D"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "Category_name": "E"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "Category_name": "F"
        }
    ],
    "message": "all category sent"
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unhandled Exception: InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430061/unhandled-exception-internallinkedhashmapstring-dynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response coming from the api is a Map, not a List,  but from the looks of things, there seems to be a list inside the map

so just do this :

```
    var res = json.decode(response.body);
    var listData = res["data"]; 
    //assuming the list inside the map is called data
    return listData;
```