# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>' flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to show data from fetchdata function

```
  List<LoanModel> _loanmodel = <LoanModel>[];

  Future<LoanModel> _fetchData() async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });

    var endpointUrl = 'http://192.168.0.23/edufund-api/Api/loansimulation.php';
    var queryParams = {
      'periodtime': periodtime,
      'interestpermonth': interestpermonth,
      'loanamountrequest': loanamountrequest,
    };
    String queryString = Uri(queryParameters: queryParams).query;
    var requestUrl = endpointUrl + '?' + queryString;
    var response = await http.get(requestUrl);
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        _loanmodel = LoanModel.fromJson(data[0]) as List<LoanModel>;

        loading = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

But it shows this error:

```
I/flutter (18921): [{"No":0,"interest":"0.00","balance":"10,000,000.00","principal":"0.00","Installment":"0.00","Status":true},{"No":1,"interest":"100,000.00","balance":"0.00","principal":"10,000,000.00","Installment":"10,100,000.00","Status":true}]
I/flutter (18921): true
E/flutter (18921): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'
E/flutter (18921): #0      _SimulatorState._fetchData.<anonymous closure> (package:fluttermysql/view/Simulator.dart:44:23)
E/flutter (18921): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1088:30)
E/flutter (18921): #2      _SimulatorState._fetchData (package:fluttermysql/view/Simulator.dart:43:7)
E/flutter (18921): <asynchronous suspension>
```

[image]

But when I hard code it, it works properly:

[image]

API output in postman as JSON:

[image]

Simulator function:

```
 static Future<LoanModel> simulators({String periodtime, String interestpermonth, String loanamountrequest, String idUser, String url}) async  {
    var url = "http://192.168.0.23/edufund-api/Api/loansimulation.php?periodtime=" + periodtime + "&interestpermonth=" + interestpermonth + "&loanamountrequest=" +loanamountrequest;
    final response = await http.get(url,headers:{"Content-Type":
    "application/json"});
    var res = LoanModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    print(response.body);
    return res;
  }
```

Is something wrong about http get or something else? Because API is working properly.

Comment: what is the type of JSON you are receiving, try figuring that out, https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51

Comment: [{"No":0,"interest":"0.00","balance":"10,000,000.00","principal":"0.00","Installment":"0.00","Status":true},{"No":1,"interest":"100,000.00","balance":"0.00","principal":"10,000,000.00","Installment":"10,100,000.00","Status":true}]

Comment: The reason is you are trying to parse the List<dynamic > with Map<String, dynamic>. Do this

for (Map i in data[0]) {
          _loanmodel.add(LoanModel.fromJson(i));
        }

Comment: I want to showing that output using parameter. with http://192.168.0.23/edufund-api/Api/loansimulation.php?periodtime=48&interestpermonth=1&loanamountrequest=15000000 this working properly because I'm hard code. but with parameter the result error

Comment: final data = jsonDecode(response.body)[0];

Comment: If it works, please let me know

Comment: it showing this error Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.

Comment: Which solution you tried?

Comment: with jsonDecode(response.body)[0]

Comment: print this value to check if the data is actullay there
final data = jsonDecode(response.body)[0];
print(data);

Comment: its null when print data

Comment: I/flutter (18921): [{"No":0,"interest":"0.00","balance":"13,000,000.00","principal":"0.00","Installment":"0.00","Status":true},{"No":1,"interest":"130,000.00","balance":"0.00","principal":"13,000,000.00","Installment":"13,130,000.00","Status":true}]
I/flutter (18921): true
I/flutter (18921): null
E/flutter (18921): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.
E/flutter (18921): Receiver: null
E/flutter (18921): Tried calling: iterator

Comment: but in response.body it showing and in postman also working properly

Comment: Print without adding 0 in response

final data = jsonDecode(response.body);

print(data);

Comment: What is the output you are getting without 0?

Comment: I/flutter (18921): [{"No":0,"interest":"0.00","balance":"12,000,000.00","principal":"0.00","Installment":"0.00","Status":true},{"No":1,"interest":"120,000.00","balance":"0.00","principal":"12,000,000.00","Installment":"12,120,000.00","Status":true}]
I/flutter (18921): true
I/flutter (18921): {status: false, message: Invalid Get Simulation Credit. Please Input the period time!}
E/flutter (18921): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Comment: too bad it didnt get value from LoanSimulation to Simulator

Comment: You are doing all this to parse the json?

Comment: yes based on value

Comment: i edit my post. Maybe i did wrong on simulators

Comment: show your code in `LoanModel` and how you declare `_loanmodel`

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should solve your problem if you want get a list

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    
   class LoanModel {
  int no;
  String interest;
  String balance;
  String principal;
  String installment;
  bool status;

  LoanModel(
      {this.no,
      this.interest,
      this.balance,
      this.principal,
      this.installment,
      this.status});

  LoanModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    no = json['No'];
    interest = json['interest'];
    balance = json['balance'];
    principal = json['principal'];
    installment = json['Installment'];
    status = json['Status'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['No'] = this.no;
    data['interest'] = this.interest;
    data['balance'] = this.balance;
    data['principal'] = this.principal;
    data['Installment'] = this.installment;
    data['Status'] = this.status;
    return data;
  }
}
```

and all it like

```
   Future<LoanModel> _fetchData() async {
        setState(() {
          loading = true;
        });
    
        var endpointUrl = 'http://192.168.0.23/edufund-api/Api/loansimulation.php';
        var queryParams = {
          'periodtime': periodtime,
          'interestpermonth': interestpermonth,
          'loanamountrequest' : loanamountrequest,
        };
        
    
    String queryString = Uri(queryParameters: queryParams).query;
            var requestUrl = endpointUrl + '?' + queryString; 
            var response = await http.get(requestUrl);
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
             print("response.body : ${response.body}");
Iterable responseData = json.decode(response.body) as List;
print("responseData : $responseData");
List<LoanModel> dataList = List<LoanModel>.from(responseData.map((model)=> LoanModel.fromJson(model)));
print("dataList : $dataList");
                setState(() {
                  _loanmodel=dataList;
                 loading = false;
              });
            }
          }
```

Comment: thanks but it showing like this type '(dynamic) => LoanModel' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'

Comment: try to declare `_loanmodel` like `List<LoanModel> _loanModel =[];`

Comment: still not solving yet

Comment: try to hard code the result, like change         `_loanmodel.addAll(loanModelFromJson(response.body));` to `String test = '[{"No":0,"interest":"0.00","balance":"10,000,000.00","principal":"0.00","Installment":"0.00","Status":true},{"No":1,"interest":"100,000.00","balance":"0.00","principal":"10,000,000.00","Installment":"10,100,000.00","Status":true}]';_loanmodel.addAll(loanModelFromJson(test));`

Comment: I already know hard code its resolve it. but thats not what the loan simulation output

Comment: let see where problem should be focus on

Comment: hard code showing but when using parameter, its error

Comment: what do you mean use parameter ? like `_loanmodel[0]` or `_loanmodel[0].no`

Comment: what i mean is based on value periodtime, interestpermonth and loanamountrequest

Comment: a new error? or still type error? hard code still be affected by the parameter?

Comment: still type error. with hard code it showing data but that's not solving the issue it make bug. when input periodtime time 12, the data will be showing 12 times with different value in listview based on json data

Comment: I update my answer, would u mind to try again. it is so weird

Comment: too bad still same [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic) => LoanModel' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'

Comment: let's try a dummy way, restart your editor and simulator, run flutter clean to rebuild the project

Comment: i got a value from simulators function but it not showing on other pages

Comment: type error solve. now remain showing data from final x =_loanmodel[i]; because the result was null

Comment: My suggestion is move `setStatus` out of `_fetchData`. In your view page, adll and wait for `_fetchData` to return list, then call `setStatus` update UI.

Comment: do you mean response.StatusCode == 200?

Comment: i already update my post. Do you mind check for update?

Comment: no, I mean in your `_fetchData`, you have a setState function to update UI. But may be in your UI part there already has some code access the data. You should move the setState out side the funtion. When you call the _fetchData, you may use `await` and `then` with setState to update UI. `streamBuilder` is also an option

Comment: sorry I'm still dont get it what you mean. cause the result of array is empty. Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. mind edit your answer?

Comment: you should show more code in your UI part, _fetchDate is done, the error should come from other part.

Comment: It it better to start a new question, it will contribute to people who has the same issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67566444/unhandled-exception-nosuchmethoderror-the-method-was-called-on-null-on-fl

Comment: would you mind  to try `print (_loanmodel);` after "allAll" function in `_fetchDate`

Comment: sure, let me try to print that model

Comment: [{"No":0,"interest":"0.00","balance":"12,000,000.00","principal":"0.00","Installment":"0.00","Status":true},{"No":1,"interest":"120,000.00","balance":"0.00","principal":"12,000,000.00","Installment":"12,120,000.00","Status":true}] this is _loanmodel output. but it received null on interest

Comment: some thing is wrong, it should be like `[Instance of 'LoanModel', Instance of 'LoanModel']`

Comment: yeah seems like that. and then this one is showing again [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic) => LoanModel' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'

Comment: hmm InternalLinkedHashMap it says. Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Comment: try again, and I need what console print this time

Comment: It get but ...
I/flutter ( 8054): [{"No":0,"interest":"0.00","balance":"1,200,000.00","principal":"0.00","Installment":"0.00","Status":true},{"No":1,"interest":"12,000.00","balance":"0.00","principal":"1,200,000.00","Installment":"1,212,000.00","Status":true}]
I/flutter ( 8054): true
E/flutter ( 8054): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Comment: I'm using method get. 
$periodtime= $_GET['periodtime'];
$interestpermonth= $_GET['interestpermonth'];
$loanamountrequest = $_GET['loanamountrequest'];

Comment: I update my answer, and please show all print in side `_fetchDate` and remove other print out outside the `_fetchDate` . The API may be the key casuing this error

Comment: hmm status false. response.body : {"status":false,"message":"Invalid Get Simulation Credit. Please Input the period time!"}

Comment: it didnt get the value from periodtime, interestpermonth and loanamountrequest

Comment: It seen that your API has some problem, it is not return correct data

Comment: But it really rely on a stable API, status true is also a wrong format data. The correct format should like you post before, a list not single map json.

Comment: when i create this static Future<LoanModel> simulators (i already post it). It showing the correct one. but how to implement to UI with array as list?

Comment: in your `simulators` , could your change it to return list

Answer (score 1):

As per your query, Make a model class like below

```
 import 'dart:convert';

   List<Test> testFromJson(String str) => List<Test>.from(json.decode(str).map((x)   =>          Test.fromJson(x)));

  String testToJson(List<Test> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Test {
 Test({
    this.no,
    this.interest,
    this.balance,
    this.principal,
    this.installment,
    this.status,
});

int no;
String interest;
String balance;
String principal;
String installment;
bool status;

factory Test.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Test(
    no: json["No"],
    interest: json["interest"],
    balance: json["balance"],
    principal: json["principal"],
    installment: json["Installment"],
    status: json["Status"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "No": no,
    "interest": interest,
    "balance": balance,
    "principal": principal,
    "Installment": installment,
    "Status": status,
};
}
```

After that you can do is

```
final data = jsonDecode(response.body);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  setState(() {
    
   _loanModel =  TestModel.fromJson(data[0]);
    
    loading = false;
  });
}



List<Test> _loanModel = <Test>[];
```

Comment: Chnage the Test class name with your own class name

Comment: the result is null from []

Comment: thanks your answer is working. now remain display of array.