# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null on flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to show data in list view like in the below (that one is hard coded)
[image]

When I changed it to list, I got this error:

```
E/flutter ( 6925): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 6925): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 6925): Tried calling: []("interest")
```

Here is my Widget Build:

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      timeDilation = 2.0;
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => false,
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          backgroundColor: kYellow,
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: Hero(
              tag: 'animasilogo',
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Image.asset('assets/img/lemonlime.png'),
              ),
            ),
            title: Text('Simulator'),
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                onPressed: () {
                  SharedPref.signOut();
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
          body: RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: () => _fetchData(),
            child: loading
                ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _loanmodel.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              final data =_loanmodel[i];
              return Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                 Text("Interest :  " + data.interest , style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.5), textAlign: TextAlign.justify),
                  Text("Balance :  " + data.balance,  style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.5),textAlign: TextAlign.justify),
                  Text("Principal : " + data.principal,  style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.5),textAlign: TextAlign.justify),
                  Text("Installment :" + data.installment,  style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.5),textAlign: TextAlign.justify),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),

                ],
              ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

For API, Model and other function, you can check my another post in [Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>' flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67564553/unhandled-exception-type-internallinkedhashmapstring-dynamic-is-not-a-sub/67564996)

Comment: It seems that the data is null. So you should verify that `data ` is not null.

Comment: the data is from value periodtime, interestpermonth and loanamountrequest. when input that value, it will be showing [{"No":0,"interest":"0.00","balance":"15,000,000.00","principal":"0.00","Installment":"0.00","Status":true},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure a part of the data you receive is not null.
the part that should receive "interest" is null and as it is the first part of data you trying to work with there is possibility that the other parts are null too

Comment: another one is Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic) => LoanModel' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'

Comment: this is because you have not changed your json map to a model