# Get Map<String, dynamic> from Map<dynamic, dynamic> flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have the code below :

```
 Map<dynamic, dynamic> result = snapshot.value;
 Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
 for (dynamic type in result.keys) {
    data[type.toString()] = result[type];
 }
 print(data);
 print(data.runtimeType);
```

but data type is `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>` and i am not able to read its value, despite the ugly hack i have done above.

The direct cast also doesn't work : `snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>` throws the error : `'_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

I need to have a Map<String, dynamic> type to be able to create my custom class Object.

`snapshot.value` has a type of dynamic, but it's a json object that returns the result of a Realtime Database query and there is no documentation about how to retrieve the value into a Flutter object.

I have tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430061/unhandled-exception-internallinkedhashmapstring-dynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of) but i can't use it as `jsonDecode()` takes a String as a parameter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When I tried Tom's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68508592) I got:

> The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

To solve this, I had to do:

```
Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value as Map);
```

In fact, since all values in my database node are booleans, I was able to do this:

```
Map<String, bool>.from(snapshot.value as Map);
```

Comment: You are right Frank, thanks for updating the answer this is now (with the latest version of the plugin) the good way to go. My answer is outdated since the SDK has changed

Comment: You're welcome @Tom3652. I needed to extract data yesterday and noticed that your answer here (while helpful) indeed didn't do the entire trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

This recent [Firecast video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXBJZD0fBa4&ab_channel=Firebase) solved my problem at 27min.

I also had an non explicit Flutter error about another nested `HashMap` in my data model object that could not be converted directly.

The solution is to use `Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value)` and this for every nested `Map` you have in your data model object

EDIT : See Frank's answer below that is the correct one for the latest version of the `firebase_database` package.

Answer (score 2):

This will recursively convert a Map<dynamic, dynamic> to Map<String, dynamic>:

```
Map<String, dynamic> dynamicMapToString(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data) {
  List<dynamic> _convertList(List<dynamic> src) {
    List<dynamic> dst = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < src.length; ++i) {
      if (src[i] is Map<dynamic, dynamic>) {
        dst.add(dynamicMapToString(src[i]));
      } else if (src[i] is List<dynamic>) {
        dst.add(_convertList(src[i]));
      } else {
        dst.add(src[i]);
      }
    }
    return dst;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> retval = {};
  for (dynamic key in data.keys) {
    if (data[key] is Map<dynamic, dynamic>) {
      retval[key.toString()] = dynamicMapToString(data[key]);
    } else if (data[key] is List<dynamic>) {
      retval[key.toString()] = _convertList(data[key]);
    } else {
      retval[key.toString()] = data[key];
    }
  }
  return retval;
}
```