# Flutter - Get Snapshot Value from FirebaseAnimatedList

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, object, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get a list of my data from my Firebase Realtime Database. I am using the widget FirebaseAnimatedList to populate and correctly query the information.

While I try to reference the data snapshot, I am getting an error. For any Swift / UIKit programmers, I am trying to produce the following:

```
if let value = snapshot.value["name"] as? String {
  print(value)
}
```

I tried calling the snapshot.value['name'] here. Then I got an error that I needed to support optional functionality, and when I added the `?.`, I got another error that I can't:

[image]

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

DatabaseReference _categoriesRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .ref()
      .child("Apps")
      .child(GlobalVariables.restaurantId)
      .child("menu")
      .child("categories");
```

```
Container(
  height: 50,
  child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    query: _categoriesRef,
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 0, 25, 0),
    itemBuilder: (
      BuildContext context,
      DataSnapshot snapshot,
      Animation<double> animation,
      int index,
    ) {
      var title = snapshot.value?.["hi there"];
      var titleText = "All ";
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 20,
          child: categoryContainer(
            titleText,
              "hello",
              index,
            ),
          width: getWidth(titleText) + 50,
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

[image: here is my data model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of a snapshot can be of many types, and it seems you need to indicate the type here.

```
var value = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value as Map);
var title = value["name"];
```

Also see: [Get Map<String, dynamic> from Map<dynamic, dynamic> flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68412968/get-mapstring-dynamic-from-mapdynamic-dynamic-flutter/71229970#71229970)