# How do I turn my firebase event into map<string, dynamic>?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I receive data from real-time db firebase and want to transform it into a map so I can convert it to an object.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("users/${uid}");

    ref.onValue.listen((event) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> data = event.snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>;
      print('my name ${data['name']}');
    });
```

The given code does not work, as there's an error appearing:

Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast.

How do I cast received data into Map<String, dynamic>?

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? Any error message? --- Also, did you see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71229970?

Comment: Thanks, everything seems to work now!