# Unhandled Exception type '_Map<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I was using Firebase in Flutter, and even though I'm using the same code, I'm getting different results or errors depending on the environment. When an error occurs, the type of snapshot.value appears as _Map, but when it works correctly, it appears as IdentityMap. I can't find any information about the _Map type when I search, so I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

The snapshot.value was the same when it was printed. The error occurs when the type changes from IdentityMap to _Map.

if you need more detail, please comment

thank you for reading

CODE

````dart
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

Future<DataSnapshot> getSnapshot(String child) async {
  return await database.ref().child(child).get();
}

Future<User> getUser(String userName) async {
  var snapshot = await getSnapshot("user/$userName");
    
  Map<String, dynamic> raw = snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>; // Error occurs

  return User.fromMap(raw);
}```
````

Comment: You'll want to do `Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value as Map);`, so that it does an actual conversion rather than just a type cast. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68412968/get-mapstring-dynamic-from-mapdynamic-dynamic-flutter/71229970#71229970