# _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, api, dart

Hello everyone I need your help I want to display the information from an api and I have an error message that tells me _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

```
 Future<List<FactureModel>> getUser() async {
    var apiUrl = '/factures';

    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(_baseUrl + apiUrl));

    try {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List<dynamic> list = await json.decode(response.body);
        print(list);
        return list.map((e) => FactureModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
      } else {
        print("Something wrong");
        return <FactureModel>[];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      print("Api request failled");
      return <FactureModel>[];
    }

    //var info = rootBundle.loadString("json/data.json");
    //List<dynamic> list = json.decode(await info);
    //print(list);
    //return Future.delayed(
    //const Duration(seconds: 5), () => list.map((e) => e).toList());
  }
}
```

Comment: Follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430061/unhandled-exception-internallinkedhashmapstring-dynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of

Answer (score 0):

store your decoded response directly into your FractureModel instead List. After then just return the list from tour FractureModel.